# Extract trajectory at a contour level from streamline in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

When plotting streamlines in MATLAB using `quiver`, `streamslice` or similar, is it possible to extract the contour line at given contour level?

Take this example (I have numerical data in my case, but I will use analytical functions in the example):

```
[X,Y] = meshgrid(0:.02:1);
Z = X.*exp(-X.^2 - Y.^2);
[DX,DY] = gradient(Z,.2,.2);

figure
imagesc([0 1], [0 1], Z)
hold on
streamslice(X,Y,DX,DY) %how to extract a trajectory at a given contour level C?
hold off
colorbar
```

If not, is it possible to obtain them otherwise? I was thinking of using `contour` in this way,

```
contour(X,Y,sqrt(DX.*DX+DY.*DY), [1 1]*0.07)
```

but this is clearly wrong when I compare to the streamlines above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hs = streamslice(X,Y,DX,DY);` as result you obtain a vector with handles to the traject lines. For example, you can get the coordinates of the first  traject line:

```
N_trajects = length(hs); % the number of all trajectories
n = 1; % the chosen trajectory
X_traject = get(hs(n),'XData');
Y_traject = get(hs(n),'YData');
```

or using new version of MATLAB:

```
X_traject = hs(n).XData;
Y_traject = hs(n).YData;
```

To extract countour lines data:

```
C = contour(X,Y,sqrt(DX.*DX+DY.*DY), [1 1]*0.07);
```

where `C` consits data with the contour lines. In your case there is one contour line only (`X_contour = C(1,:)`, `Y_contour = C(2,:)`). In the case of many contour levels, to extract them see [here](https://fr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/230934-how-to-extract-x-and-y-position-of-contour-line) or [here](https://fr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/251865) or using [this](https://fr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/38863-extract-contour-data-from-contour-matrix-c).

Now we know the coordinates of the trajectory and contour level. Thus you can find the point(s) of intersection between the trajectory and the contour level.

Comment: Thanks, that is helpful. However, is it possible to find the trajectory at particular contour level?

Comment: Is it relevant to your question now?